# can't get the back end data when I run a react app from other device

Tags: reactjs, django, networking

I have a project with react on the front and django/python and postgres on the back

Everything goes ok on the computer, but if I run it from another device, in the same network, the data can’t be loaded, it says axios network error

I found my Ip with ipconfig, suppose it's 192.xxx.xxx.xxx, then I set in the mobile device http:// 192.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000, it runs the application but the data can't be found there, it says AxiosError: Network Error

My computer recognizes the wifi network 2.4, then I connect the phone to the 2.4 network

In the axios call, I set the address as:

```
const response = await axios.get(
         `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/whole_menu/${restaurantId}`
);
```

(I’m not using localhost)

But I still get the network error in the phone, but in the computer, everything is ok

What could it be?

Thanks in advance

Rafael

**EDIT**:

I realise that the calls don't reach the backend, axios rejects the device with the network error

If I follow the react ouput, it doesn't work either

Local:            http://localhost:3000
On Your Network:  http://192.xxx.xxx.xxx:3000

In the django server, in settings.py, I have:

CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = ("http://127.0.0.1:3000",)

if I set:

CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True

I get the same error

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't update your firewall. For other devices to be able to communicate with you pc you have to what's called open your port for tcp traffic, in this case port 3000. You can find how to do so for example here: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-open-port-in-windows-10-firewall/f38f67c8-23e8-459d-9552-c1b94cca579a
Be aware that others on your network can now send traffic to your laptop. Therefor it is wise to revert this when you are done testing.

Comment: I followed this link: https://pureinfotech.com/open-port-firewall-windows-10/#open_port_firewall, I opened the port, but still the same. It's so strange

Comment: I note a thing, the application has always opened on the other device, but it's the axios call to the backend api what fails with an Axios Network Error (a generic one). Even the backend doesn't get the request, no errors shown there. Remember, I set cors in the backend as CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL = True. Could it tell you something?

Comment: Moreover, my backend api is using PostgreSQL could it affect something?